# Import fail when using workon (python)

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi

I am using python 3 and OpenCV 2.7 for image processing, now I want to add LCD for my raspberry-pi. I have 2 scripts for testing:

(image processing)

```
from imutils.object_detection import non_max_suppression
from imutils import path
import RPi.GPIO as GIP
....
```

to run this script, I have to use `workon cv` command before calling `python imgprocessing.py`. If I not using  `workon cv`, it will produce

```
No Module named imutils.object_detection    

:---------------------------------    
(LCD)

    import Adafruit_CharLCD as LCD
```

and it also works, but only if I didn't use `workon cv` before calling the `python LCD.py`. If I use `workon cv` before, it will produce error

> No Module named Adafruit_CharLCD

How to combine both scripts given their "unique" characteristics?

Comment: `workon cv` change your path, check your path(default) and `sys.path.append(default_path)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the script, that you normally use, with `workon cv` as follows:

```
cv/bin/python imgprocessing.py
```

that way it will use the correct interpreter and find the `imutils` package.

Comment: thanks for your quick response, but when I try it i got `No such file or directory` error. Is it also possible to search for the opencv location?

Comment: You have to supply the full path to `cv`. There is a searchpath but the easiest is probably `workon cv` and then `which python`

Answer (score 1):

Problems is solved, thanks to @Anthon and @dsgdfg who open up my mind. The solution is by still using `workon cv` but adding `sys.path.append(*AdafruitGPIOfullpath*)` on Adafruit_LCD library